# Eclipse - is it possible to jump to a particular package?

Tags: java, eclipse, package

Say i'm looking at some file, and i'd like to see if there are similar files in a different package. I don't really know what the different files might be called - they were coded by different people, so could well be named differently.

I do know they're *probably* in a package of roughly the same name - for example, if i'm looking at a file in the `com.sandwiches.ham.artisan` package, and i think there should be a similar (although, in this case, sadly unrelated) file in the `com.sandwiches.avocado.artisan` package, what is the fastest way to jump to said package and check it out?

I'm fed up of scrolling through reams of artisan sanwiches, its making me hungry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, no matter what, you are going to have to do some typing. There *is* a Go-to navigation item for packages, its just not bound to any quick keys. To bind it to a key combination of your choice, do the following:

Eclipse->Preferences, and type in Keys as your filter.

[image: Eclipse Preferences - Key Bindings]

Search for the Go To Package command, click on the Binding entry field, and type whatever keys you want to use for the keybindings (in my screenshot I have it set to Command-Shift-0). Then click OK to save and close the preferences dialog.

After that, typing your chosen key bindings will bring up a package explorer that lets you type in whatever package you want and navigate to it.

[image]

Comment: seems as close as i'm going to get - and its pretty darn close. The exact thing i was looking for, actually. This is going to help the weightloss regimen no end

Comment: Glad to help. Send the sandwiches my way - it's lunchtime!

Comment: for some reason i cannot get this to open when i'm looking at a file - i had to tie the package explorer view to one shortcut, and then the go to package to another. So i press two key combos to get to it - sigh

Comment: The current preferences dialog does not allow you to leave the command context blank, which is required in order to have the command binding be 'always-active'. Unfortunate really. If you have your package explorer always open (which I believe is the default behaviour of both the Java and JEE perspectives), you can just click on any package and then fire your key binding. But two actions are required afaict, yes.

Comment: that's ok - i was assuming this was an impossible situation in eclipse so you already cleared the park. I actually always keep the package explorer on "fast view" with a key board shortcut to get to it, so this isn't a big deal for me

Answer (score 1):

From the Breadcrumb (press `Alt+Shift+B` to open it) it is quite quick to navigate your way through the sandwich menu ehm I meant packages structure...

Comment: -1: This doesn't let you jump to a particular package, it just lets you scroll the list of packages. The asker is already doing that.

Comment: @TomAnderson: from the breadcrumb it is faster to navigate the packages than from the package explorer (because of its position). Do you have any better shortcut or solution?

Answer (score -1):

**Ctrl + Shift + R** its a good shortcut to find files in every package in your proyects, i use it everytime... hope it help...

Comment: -1: Control-shift-R doesn't open packages, only files. This question is very specifically about packages.

Comment: @TomAnderson you are right, i didnt express myself right, correcte the mistake... Thanks for the comment...